# Unable to boot Ubuntu from an external SSD

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, ssd

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 in an USB flash drive and it boots perfectly fine. Then I cloned this drive to an SSD on Windows using MiniTool Partition Wizard (full disk clone, not specific partitions). This SSD is connected to the computer using an USB-to-SATA adapter.

The problem is that this USB SSD doesn't appear as an option in the boot menu in one computer (Dell Inspiron 13 7375). In this computer the USB flash drive boots fine, but not the cloned SSD.

I tried in another computer and both drives boot fine, so clearly the drives are OK. The fact that the first computer can boot from the USB flash drive but not from the USB SSD is puzzling.

Do you have any idea what may be going on? Thanks.

Comment: What's the device that doesn't detect the SSD (manufacturer, model, etc.)?

Comment: We need to know the computer and motherboard models, and the SSD.

Comment: The one that doesn't detect the drive is a Dell Inspiron 13 7375

Comment: @Paul - [Edit] your question.  When you cloned the disk did you clone the entire disk or just specific partitions?

Comment: Edited. It's a full disk clone, not specific partitions.